# Nginx save file to local disk

Tags: nginx, cache

My case is:

> In our China company, we have to access one web server in USA
>   headquarter through Internet. But network is too slow, and we download
>   many big image files. All our developers have to wait.
>
> So we want to setup a Nginx which acts as reverse proxy, its upstream
>   is our USA web server. Question is can we make Nginx save the image
>   files from USA web server into its local disk? I mean let Nginx act as
>   one cache server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, nginx can be used as reverse cache and cache files to disk. Here is example configuration: http://wiki.nginx.org/ReverseProxyCachingExample